# What is the most compact and/or efficient way to extract multiple (non-consecutive) values from a list using indexing

Tags: c#, list, indexing

I have the following list:

```
List<int> listOfInt = new List<int> {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
```

I am now given a list of indices pointing to the values to be extracted from listOfInt:

```
int[] idxList= new int[] { 2, 4, 1 };
```

Now, I want to extract all the values from listOfInt by index (as per provided idxList) into another list.
Here is what I came up with, which seems to work, but I would like to get rid of this foreach loop. How can this be done?

```
List<int> newList= new List<int>();
foreach(var idx in idxList) newList.Add( listOfInt.ElementAt(idx) );
```

Solution:
{30, 50, 20} will be written into newList

Comment: You said "efficient", but it seems you are looking for simpler/better looking code, not code with better performance, right?

Comment: Well, it depends, can we do more efficient without the foreach loop?

Comment: Something has to loop whether you like it or not, since that is the case, now we are down to micro-optimization, i suggest getting a benchmarker and trying a couple of things

Comment: Ok thanks, are you saying my solution is already optimal?

Comment: This question might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ than in here, but check their site guidelines

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I will check it out!

Comment: "but I would like to get rid of this foreach loop" why? It works as expected. If you're trying to optimise this, then it feels like premature optimisation.

Comment: I guess it is a tradeoff. Using Linq seems to be the alternative. I had the feeling I was not coding as a C# programmer when using a foreach loop, but rather like a C programmer. Hence not using all the power provided by the C# language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short way to do this, using Linq: `idxList.Select(i => listOfInt[i]).ToList()`

Comment: Oh, I like that. Nice one! How does it compare to using the foreach loop? Is it more/less/same type of efficiency?

Comment: @stackMeUp the source code for Select uses a foreach

Comment: this is just a short hand for it, as far as I know, using linq imposes some overhead

Comment: @stackMeUp I recommend you read the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995553/whats-the-difference-between-select-new-vs-foreach-new) question.

Comment: +1 @Sohaib Jundi: What I like about your solution is that I can return the entire result into a variable. When using a foreach loop, newList will have to be cleared each time I enter the loop.

Answer (score 3):

> Well, it depends, can we do more efficient without the foreach loop?

`foreach()` gets an enumerator and walks over the list. Any other solution you can come up with, will ultimately have to do the same, because you need to handle each item in your index list.

So no, you can't make this more efficient. Or maybe you could, if you write out all requirements and assumptions, but no way this is going to be the performance bottleneck of your code.

CPU cycles are cheap. Terse code is expensive, to both write and read, because of the mental overhead.

You could use Linq as @Sohaib demonstrates below, but that won't be noticeably more efficient.

Comment: I appreciate the tips, thanks. I guess I need to become confortable with both approaches (efficient and readable).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to omit `foreach` you can use this:

```
var result = idxList.Select(i => listOfInt.ElementAt(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding items to `newList` one by one. This will create some unnecessary memory allocations. Better to give new List hint about resulting size.

```
var listOfInt = new List<int> { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
var idxList = new [] { 2, 4, 1 };

var newList = new List<int>(idxList.Length);

for (int i = 0; i < idxList.Length; i++)
    newList[i] = listOfInt[idxList[i]];
```

Also, `for` loop tends to be faster than `foreach` when iterating thru List ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/365658/2438165)).

Comment: Yes that is what I realised and why using Linq as suggested by @Sohaib Jundi seems to be the way to go. Thanks.